# Logical expression in OWL

Tags: logic, rdf, owl, semantic-web, turtle-rdf

How is a logical expression written in OWL?
Any expression which contains "and" and "or" operator would do.
Also provide some hints how client (for example, java program with OWL parser) must resolve this expression to true or false values.
Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: The [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-overview/) have you seen? In particular also the semantics part? OWL semantics is based on Description Logics, so this is the underlying logical formalism with its typical set-based semantics from model theory

Comment: I know. I am working on application part. Not much into theory. I have IRIs in string formats.. I want certain statuses to hold true before i continue my next step of orchestration.. An example would do..

Comment: I don't understand your comment, sorry. "I have IRIs in string formats" -> and now? How does this matter? It's not clear what you're asking, especially as you didn't provide any running example. Please extend your question with more details

Comment: For real examples, take a look inside the BioPortal snapshots. Hundreds of ontologies that are actually used in real world applications. https://zenodo.org/record/439510#.WiJc_xN-p64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need to look at [SWRL](https://www.w3.org/Submission/SWRL/) where you can also find examples.